# Function to give variable a number, but changes depending on how many times it's been run

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a blackjack game, and I want to have the option to deal additional cards, but what I've run up against is I'm trying to make a function that will deal additional cards, but I'm not sure the best way to do that. I have an idea on how to do it, but I'm not clear on how I would accomplish it.

Idea:
Have a function that will deal addition cards, and will +1 a variable counting how many cards the player already has, starting at 2, the first time the function is run, will give the player card #3. The function would then randomly give a card, and then return the card, (perhaps playerCardThree, playerCardFour) with a limit of 5 cards allowed at a time. Here is an example of what I'd like it to do, but I'm not sure if it'd work.

```
def deal():
    playerCardTotal + 1
    if playerCardTotal >= 5:
        print("Error detected, returning...")
        play()
    newPlayerCard = randint(1,10)
    print("You are given card ",playerCardTotal,"it is a",newPlayerCard)
    newPlayerCard = playerCard(4)
```

If someone could help me do something similar, or perhaps lead me to a way that would accomplish the goal cleaner, as I'm sure what I've thought up isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: If you want to combine a function with data ("a variable counting how many cards the player has"), you should consider using a class.

Comment: `,,,but I'm not sure if it'd work` - Does it work?  What is your question?  Unfortunately SO is not a discussion forum.  Pleas take the time to read [ask].

Comment: Try += 1 rather than +1

Comment: You can encapsulate the state either in a class or in a generator. The generator pattern most closely fits the 'function with a state' requirement you are formulating, while the use of a class better reflects what you actually want to do.

Comment: I would indeed work with a class. `Hand` seems a reasonable name, with a `max_limit` variable and a `deal` method with adds a random card to the hand and returns which card was added

Answer (score 1):

How about using a counter within a class, which will automatically increase each time you instantiate it. Then each card will be an instance. You can raise an error when the counter exceeds 5, as you described in your question. A simplified starting point for your game might be something like this (you should elaborate it as you need):

```
import random

class MyGame():
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        MyGame.counter += 1

    def deal_card(self):
        self.card = random.randint(1,10)
        if self.get_count() > 5:
            raise RuntimeError('too many cards have been played')
        print("You are given card #", self.get_count())

    def get_count(self):
        return MyGame.counter


a = MyGame()
a.deal_card()
b = MyGame()
b.deal_card()
```